# Question about irreducible polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Is this polynomial: $irr(\sqrt{3 -\sqrt{6}}, \mathbb{Q})$ irreducible?

Here is what I did $ a = \sqrt{3 -\sqrt{6}}$

$a^2 = 3 - \sqrt{6}$

$a^2 - 3 = -\sqrt{6}$

$(a^2 - 3)^2 = 6$

Our polynomial ends up being $a^4 - 6a^2 + 9$ Which I can obviously factor into 2 nonconstant polynomials. Am I misunderstanding the definiton? My problem set says it's irreducible

Comment: Is it irreducible because it;s zero is irrational and the polynomials are embedded in the field of rational numbers?

Comment: With $irr(\sqrt{3-\sqrt{6}},\Bbb Q)$ you mean the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{3-\sqrt{6}}$ over $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: Yes sir. That is exactly what I mean

Comment: I believe you should get $a^4-6a-27$ from $(a^2-3)^2=6$.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski Why is that? It should be $a^4-6a^2+3=0$.

Comment: Oops, I was squaring the 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polynomial $f(x)=irr(\sqrt{3-\sqrt{6}},\Bbb Q)$ is irreducible *almost* by definition, i.e., this is the smallest polynomial (in the degree sense) such that $f\left(\sqrt{3-\sqrt{6}}\right)=0$, if you could factor $f(x)$ as

$$f(x)=g(x)h(x)$$

with $g,h$ non-constant polynomials, then

$$f\left(\sqrt{3-\sqrt{6}}\right)=g\left(\sqrt{3-\sqrt{6}}\right)\cdot h\left(\sqrt{3-\sqrt{6}}\right)=0$$

Can you see what contradiction arises here? I suggest you finish the proof.

---

Now, let's focus on your proceeding. The relation you've found is correct:

$$(a^2-3)^2=6$$

If you expand that square, you get

$$a^4-6a^2+9=6$$

Which is the polynomial that $a$ annihilates? It's not

$$f(x)=x^4-6x^2+9$$

Since $f(a)=6$, the polynomial is actually

$$f(x)=x^4-6x^2+3$$

This polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: First of all, cool name, man. Second of all, I see what you are saying It pretty much is the polynomial that makes this zero. But you can factor that into two polynomials with rational coefficients. A matter of fact it factors back into $(x^2 -3)^2$. Is the definition more along the lines of " when you factor it into as small as possible it doesn't need irrational coefficients? Because I could factor it further into $(a+\sqrt{3})^2(a - \sqrt{3})^2$

Comment: That's what I wrote at the end, the polynomial is not $x^4-6x^2+9$ (which, of course, can be factored), since you have $a^4-6a^2+9=6$, you have $a^4-6a^2+3=0$ so the polynomial that vanishes at $a$ is $x^4-6x^2+3$, which is irreducible **over $\Bbb Q$**, meaning with this that it cannot be factored into two non-constant polynomials with entries from $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Well, either way it would factor into 2 polynomials that are indeed in Q, only when I furtherly reduce those does it end up with coefficients in the irrational numbers. But thanks for all the help, man

Comment: @user121615 How would it factor?

Comment: Ooooh wait, I get it. The polynomial has a gap in it at that number! That's why we say it's irreducible in Q

Comment: Because I could factor it into $(a^2 - 3)^2$ . And this is two polynomials which have rational coefficients. But I understand now that I wasn't looking at the definition and what was asked of me correctly

Comment: Please, I will say it again: the polynomial IS NOT $x^4-6x^2+9$ (which, of course, can be factored), the polynomial that vanishes at $a$ IS $x^4-6x^2+3$, which cannot be factored over $Q$

Comment: haha! Oh man you are right. I had it all wrong. I indeed can't factor that. Sorry man. I feel silly. I somehow in my head that I could factor that. Funny how my brain works sometimes. Thanks for all the help

Comment: No problem. however, it doesn't matter wheter you can factor this polynomial or not, the minimal polynomial will always be irreducible by definition (if you could factor $x^4-6x^2+3$, the minimal would be one of those factors). Please, consider choosing an accepted answer to this and the other posts you've made to thanks the effort of those who answer.

Comment: I pretty much always pick best answer man. I got you :)